create package python import error not import files
I have this folder stu.
Root Folder- Project:
project folder in /Document/office/
| folder
-> File
Project
-> config.py
-> app.py
| Src
  -> abc.py
  -> xyz.py
| test
  -> testcase.py

1 case  I want to import config.py in abc.py and xyz.py and in testcase.py
2 case i want to import src.abc in app.py
3 case i want to import abc in test.testcase.py 

How can I do thin in Python?
i want to import like this:
import config

import src.abc


Which files do you directly execute and which ones are only imported by other files?

i want something like django i include file from any where in any file
i have to define path every where

"include file from any where in any file" Good luck then. A good project has a single directly executable file at top of its hierarchy. I cannot help you with this mess you ask for.

from path_to_module import module_name as named_by_you

if you need more please read this : How do I import other Python files?
